# angularjs moment parse format

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datetime, momentjs, angular-moment

I have a ng-repeat that display the following expression

```
{{date}} // 2-1-2017
```

When I use angular-moment

```
{{date | amDateFormat:'DD'}}
```

I got 1, which I'm expecting 2. how to make moment know my format is actually `dd-mm-yyyy` not `mm-dd-yyy` in the view? I don't want to parse it at my controllers level as it's complicated.

Comment: What is the type of `date` variable (date, sting, moment object)? Do you have warning in the console?

Answer (score 3):

According to the docs, AngularJs has a built-in [filter for date](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date) which can be used with the following set:

```
{{ date_expression | date : format : timezone}}
```

So that you can use it like:

```
{{ date | date:'dd-MM-yyyy'}}
```

However if you use moment's date filter, it has to be a moment date (i.e., complete date with timezone defined) object and you can filter it in the same way that angular does.

```
{{ date | amDateFormat:'dd-MM-yyyy' }}
```

Comment: I want to display the date only, like 2.

Comment: You mean I use angularjs date filter to format and do something with moment?

Comment: @JessieEmerson You can use de format argument as `'dd'` so btu actually you may have problems with your date object and how you are parsing its format.

Comment: the date is a string actually.

Comment: @JessieEmerson what about `date = new Date('2-1-2017');`?

Comment: Where should I put that? in controller? I don't want to touch controller, there are bunch of dates coming from there, and it's nested.

Comment: @JessieEmerson please take a look at [my updated answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41399263/4131048) that uses [`amParse`](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment#amparse-filter) filter without modifying the controller.

Answer (score 3):

You can use angular built-in [filter for date](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date) (as suggested in other answers), if your input is:

- a JavaScript Date object
- a number that represents milliseconds (this can be also a string)
- a string in ISO 8601 format (e.g. `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.sssZ`, `yyyy-MM-dd` etc)

---

Your `date` is a string with a format that is **not** ISO 8601, so you have to change the way you parse `2-1-2017` into a date.

You can parse your string in your controller using [`moment(String, String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) as shown in the following example:

```js
angular.module('MyApp',['angularMoment'])
.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.dates = [
    // Wrong way to parse string
    moment('2-1-2017').toDate(),
    // Parse string specifying format
    moment('2-1-2017', 'D-M-YYYY').toDate()
  ];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-moment/1.0.1/angular-moment.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="date in dates">
    <span>angular-moment: {{date | amDateFormat:'DD'}}</span>
    <span>angular date filter: {{date | date:"dd"}}</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you don't want to modify your controller you can use angular moment [`amParse`](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment#amparse-filter) filter. As the docs says, this filter:

> Parses a custom-formatted date into a moment object that can be used with the `am-time-ago` directive and the other filters.

So in your case, you can use the code shown in the following example:

```js
angular.module('MyApp',['angularMoment'])
.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.dates = [
    '2-1-2017', // February 2 2017
    '15-1-2017' // January 15 2017
  ];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-moment/1.0.1/angular-moment.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="date in dates">
    <span>angular-moment: {{date | amParse:'D-M-YYYY' | amDateFormat:'DD'}}</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem could be related in how you build your date object

```
new Date("2-1-2017") ; // Wed Feb 01 2017
```

If I do this, 1 refers to the day, which is correct. 
The date filter parse the date based on the object it receive, you should look for a correct Date format for your input date.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the angular filter, like:

```
{{date | date:'dd-MM-yyyy'}}
```